# add a variable in href using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in javascript i want to add a javascript variable in

```
<a href="link.com/variable,variable2"></a>
```

i use some javascript like this but it not working

HTML

```
<ul id="direction"></ul>`
```

JS

```
var abc = 'link/';
var cba = 'hello';
document.getElementById('directions').innerHTML = '<a href=https://"' + abc +cba+'">Link</a>';`
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the actual outcome? And what did you expect?

Comment: Your quotes are incorrect. The code results in `<a href=https://"link/hello">Link</a>`. Fix that.

Comment: Your element is "direction" but your code looks for "directions".

Comment: `<a>` is not a valid child of `<ul>`

Answer (score 2):

This code should work, make sure the html id matches the getElementById and use the right quotes as mentioned before.

You want to add a href to a list but you should add a li first, in my example I use a div tag.

```
var name = 'google';
var ext = '.com';

document.getElementById('direction').innerHTML = '<a href="https://www.' + name + ext +'">Link</a>';
```

> A better way to do this would be by using backticks `` < these like so:

```
var name = 'google';
var ext = '.com';
var link = 'Link';

document.getElementById('direction').innerHTML = `<a href="https://www.${name}${ext}">${link}</a>`;
```

Comment: _"in my example I use a div tag"_: that part is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, fixed ID, and quotes:

```
document.getElementById("direction").innerHTML='<a href="https://'+var1+var2+'">Link</a>'
```

Or maybe better:

```
var node=document.createElement("A")
node.setAttribute("href","https://"+var1+var2)
document.getElementById("direction").appendChild(node)
```

I hope that this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend avoiding using `innerHTML` in most cases! The following accomplishes what you want programmatically without needing to generate HTML strings:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let abc = 'link/';
  let cba = 'hello';
  let container = document.getElementById('direction');
  let link = container.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
  link.setAttribute('href', `https://${abc}${cba}`);
  link.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Link'));
};
```

```html
<ul id="direction"></ul>
```

Comment: `direction` is a list, not an anchor.

Comment: Ah you're right! My mistake.